# How do I retrieve user email from Firebase Firestore and send it to an email intent when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to fetch user email using `FirebaseAuth` and open an email intent to show the email fetched automatically in the email.

I have tried to do the intent however I need help to get the email from `Firebase` and link it to email intent:

```
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailButton = findViewById(R.id.openEmailButton);

        emailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userInformation();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
            }
        });


    public void userInformation(){
        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
           email = user.getEmail();
        }
    }
```

Instead of `emailaddress@emailaddress.com` I want the email address fetched from `Firebase`.

Comment: Then first you need store you user email in firebase then get it

Comment: The firebase auth saves the email can I retrieve from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need help to get the email from firebase

If you need add the email from the Firebase authentication to the intent, please note that you're almost there. Just add the `email` that you got from the `FirebaseUser` object in `userInformation()` method to your intent object. So please change the following line of code:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
```

to

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
```